Android TV emulator keeps getting closed automatically
I am running a flutter app in debug mode in Android tv emulator (Android TV (720p) API 30), after first few minutes and few hot restarts the emulator gets killed on its own. The error in the vs code shows
[ERR] The Android emulator exited with code 1 after startup
[ERR] Android emulator stderr:
[ERR] WARNING | Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): Vulkan
[ERR] WARNING | *** No gRPC protection active, consider launching with the -grpc-use-jwt flag.***
[ERR] CANNOT TRANSLATE guest DNS ip
[ERR] CANNOT TRANSLATE guest DNS ip

I did not find any solutions for the same problem.

try app run in real device.

In real TV it is working but want it to run on the emulator, because sometimes i don't have access to the real TV.

i think their is GPU or memory problem that reason your emulator restart.
may i know which sdk version of emulator

I am using android 11 (API level 30 ).

I was not able to understand the reason why the error occurred, but I will share what helped me resolve the error. In, Android Studio, updating the SDK tools and installing the Android Emulator Hypervisor (installer) from the list of SDK tools got rid off the error.
